# Increase fastcgi_read_timeout for single route

Tags: php, nginx

I have the following Nginx configuration for forwarding requests to a PHP-FPM backend:

```
server {
    ...

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~* \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/index.php;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param PATH_TRANSLATED $document_root$fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
    }

}
```

One specific route in the app needs a slightly longer php `max_execution_time` setting.  I've configured this successfully and verified it works by setting a longer `fastcgi_read_timeout` in the above config.

However, I don't need this to be applied to every single route.  I'm guessing I need a nested location somewhere but nothing I've tried seems to work!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `fastcgi_read_timeout` directive does not appear to accept dynamic values, so a separate location block for the *special route* will be required. Looking at your configuration file, I assume the *special route* is a unique URI processed by the `/index.php` script. Something like this should work:

```
location ^~ /special/route/uri {
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/index.php;
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 100s;
}
```

You can use a prefix location with the `^~` modifier (as above) to override the regex location that usually processes PHP files. Alternatively, you can use a regex location, but place it *above* the existing regex location so that it takes precedence.

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for location syntax.

Comment: Apologies, I was slightly premature. The extra location block did work - it allowed me to set a different `fastcgi_read_timeout` for the special route. However, it broke the routing in my app. To fix this I had to manually set some `fastcgi_param` vars to fix the script name and document URI. It may not be the cleanest solution but works for my use case.